# How can I iterate over each item in json Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, loops, openweathermap

I'm trying to iterate over each item to print place name, temp, feels like, humidity and pressure. when I print each variable I see correct values, e.g.,`print(w.temperature);` then `print(w);` prints out values I have no idea about..

Comment: Can you include the full json

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes, I just did

Answer (score 1):

try using futurebuilder when printing data
i'm not sure if you might be trying to reach them before the data arrives

Comment: Can you share the code? Do you mean in the main dart use futurebuilder instead of listview builder? I'm not quite sure how I can do that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

On your model class, variables are nullable

```dart
class WeatherData {
  String? placeName;
```

`Text` widget doesn't take null value, therefore you need to handle it.

You can provide default value like

```dart
Text('${weather.placeName?? "default value"}',
```

Or don't render while it is null

`if(weather.placeName!=null)Text('${weather.placeName!}'`

Check, I'm using `!` after making sure it will never get null.

Check [this to understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I'm using WeatherData to render both current weather and forecast. I can only render current weather with the placeName even though it can take null value.. I'm not sure where the error is coming from...

Comment: even after setting defualt value in case the value is null, I still get the same error that says "type null is not a subtype of type 'WeatherData'..

Comment: make `WeatherData` nullable, and check while using it like this

Comment: thanks. I implement  ```@override String toString();``` in weatherdata.dart as Instance of WeatherData gets printed out. still no output gets printed out.. any ideas?

Comment: because you are not getting any data and that is `null`

Comment: Thank you, I changed the code.. I'm still unable to get the output for forecast.. I have updated the questions with code. can you tell where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include full json

Comment: yes I did.. I can print out values correctly if I run print(w.temperature) but then when I run print(w) the output doesn't contain all six values I need..

Comment: Are you mentioning decimal point issue?

Comment: yes.. I'm not sure where the values coming from for ```print(w);``` e.g., I run```print(w.temperature);```it prints out values like 

I/flutter ( 1816): 5.48
I/flutter ( 1816): 5.22
I/flutter ( 1816): 4.63
I/flutter ( 1816): 6.3 but print(w);  does't print out those values.. I need to print out 6 variable values when I run ```print(w);```